# I want to add items dynamically to the MainActivity but when I fire the intent only one item(name) is added

Tags: android

I am firing an explicit intent from my second Activity to my first. The second Activity has an Array list and an array adapter, which has some items and I am sending that to the Main Activity. The problem is that I can't add the items dynamically. By dynamically I mean One item after another. I have two texViews in the main activity but the both receive the same item name.

**Second Activity**

```
    ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<>();
    itemNames.add("Apple");
    itemNames.add("Milk");
    itemNames.add("Rice");
    itemNames.add("Mango");
    itemNames.add("Egg");
    itemNames.add("Bread");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemNames);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(itemList.this, "You clicked on:" + itemNames.get(position), 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent sendItems = new Intent(itemList.this, MainActivity.class);
            sendItems.putExtra("items", itemNames.get(position));
            startActivity(sendItems);
        }
    });
```

[image: This is what the Second Activity looks like]

**Main Activity** `

```
TextView itemView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView itemView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Intent receiveItems = getIntent();
    String receive = receiveItems.getStringExtra("items");
    itemView.setText(receive);
    itemView2.setText(receive);
    btnMain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, itemList.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

[image: This is the main Activity]

Comment: you are actually sending only one item as a string to the second activity and displaying this string in two textviews

Comment: @BilalRammal how do I send them individually and show them in text view(s).